# Installing HTTP /2 webserver

Tags: http, webserver, spdy, http2, h2o

I am trying to do some performance analysis of HTTP/1.1 and HTTP /2. But I have not been successful in installing the later one. I need both the protocols from the same implementation (e.g. H2O). The first problem I got while installing H2O is the openssl version in ubuntu 14.04. The I updated the version to 1.0.2 as suggested by [1](https://github.com/h2o/h2o). Then I got the following error messages:

```
    In function `h2o_socket_ssl_get_selected_protocol':
    /tmp/h2o/lib/common/socket.c:499: undefined reference to        `SSL_get0_alpn_selected'
CMakeFiles/h2o.dir/lib/common/socket.c.o: In function `h2o_ssl_register_alpn_protocols':
/tmp/h2o/lib/common/socket.c:542: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [h2o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/h2o.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anybody please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Nginx.  There is a lot more support for it.  H2O is a little more complicated to setup and the docs aren't as well written.